# VB.NET How to display picture collection in a 3x2 grid?

Tags: vb.net, scroll

I am trying to create a view panel where it displays 3 pictures horizontally and 2 pictures vertically (3x2 grid) out of a collection of 100 images whos image file location I get from a dataset. Basically I want to be able to scroll through the collection so that I can select an image from the collection and then work with it.

What control will allow me to do this as obviously I don't want to be loading 100 images into memory just to be able to scroll a panel?

Comment: What kind of application? Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: `obviously I don't want to be loading 100 images ` How can you show an image without loading it?  Please read: [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: Windows Forms  using VS2015

Comment: You seem to be looking for magic that doesn't exist.  All you would do is create the appropriate number of `PictureBox` controls and then set there `Image` properties as appropriate. As you scroll, you'll move an `Image` from one `PictureBox` to the next until it leaves the last one and you either keep it around in case it's needed again later or dispose it and reload the file later if required. I'd suggest that you put the controls inside a `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: @Plutonix, I assume they mean that they don't want to load all 100 images up front.